# Get file word count using bash script WITHOUT wc command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

Is there an efficient way to use a `bash` script that will count the number of words in a specified file without utilizing the `wc` command?

Preferably, is it possible to do this with a simple loop?

I am having trouble coming up with a way to do this and everywhere I've already checked on Google uses the `wc` command.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49820161/edit) to include more information.  For example, would you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Note the "practical" criteria in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you're going to specify that something be implemented without standard tools, please describe the practical limitation that leads to this constraint.

Comment: BTW, if I were writing this myself, I'd use a `while read` loop as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). See also [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for instructions on how to modify that to read each line into an array of words, and to ask an array for its length.

Comment: Your forth word, "efficient" eliminates anything written in an interpreted language like *nix shells. A compiled `c-lang` program will be much more "efficient". Agree with all above comments, but if you need to continue this project for some reason other than course work (the only reason I can see for this). please update your Q to indicate why a shell solution is required. Good luck!

Comment: A) Why? B) Do you have a special, operational definition of `word` in mind?

Comment: Okay, so the reason of this inconvenient way is because my teacher gave us some questions and this was the one and only that I could just not do. The goal is to practice making loops.

Comment: `set -a words; while read words; do ((tot+=${#words})) ; done < file ; echo $tot` or something like that. Don't have time now t research exact sytnax for using `words` as an array. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This fuzzy code relies on `tr` and `dd`, and counts squeezed whitespace, which isn't always the same as the number of words, but it's not far off:

```
word_count() { tr -s '\n[:space:]'  ' ' |  tr -cd '[:space:]' | 
               dd of=/dev/null 2>&1 | tail -1 | (read a b ; echo $a ) ; }
```

Consider the number of words in `man bash`, followed by actual `wc` results:

```
man bash | word_count
man bash | wc --words
```

Output:

```
46139
46139
```

In this instance they're the same.  But `word_count` *is* susceptible to off-by one errors if:

- There are spaces but no alphanumerics:

  ```
  printf ' \n' | word_count
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  1
  ```
- There's a word, but no white space:

  ```
  printf 'foo' | word_count
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  0
  ```

Comment: and now repeat with `time man bash | w...` :), please. Oh, nearly identical!